# removing div from a jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've developed a "Google-Maps-like" user interface for my intranet where users can add steps to calculated routes and distances. I'm using sortable `div`s to reorder steps. Now I want to remove steps, but my JavaScript/jQuery code doesn't work at all. Can you help me?

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});



    function addStep() {
        var temp = $('.template').clone();
        $(temp).removeClass("template");
        $(temp).addClass("sort");
        $('#sortable').append(temp);

    }
    function removeStep() {

        $(this).closest('div.sort').remove();
        $("#sortable").sortable('refresh');
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
//template to add new step
 <div class="template">
        <input type="text" name="addressN" value="" class="address" />
        <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeStep();" />
    </div>
//sortable list of step
    <div id="sortable">
        <div class="sort">
            <input type="text" name="Start" value="" class="address" />
        </div>
        <div class="sort">
            <input type="text" name="End" value="" class="address" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Route!" onclick="showLocation(); return false;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Step" onclick="addStep(); return false;" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s something wrong with your `addStep()` function. I’ll try to explain by adding some comments to your original code:

```
function addStep() {
 // Here, you store a reference to the jQuery Object containing the clone in the var temp.
 var temp = $('.template').clone();
 // Here, you wrap temp (which already is a jQuery Object) inside $().
 // Fix: replace '$(temp)' by 'temp'
 $(temp).removeClass('template');
 $(temp).addClass('sort');
 $('#sortable').append(temp);
}
```

After fixing this, plus some additional optimizations, this becomes:

```
function addStep() {
 $('.template').clone().removeClass('template').addClass('sort').appendTo('#sortable');
}
```

---

Also, your `removeStep()` function incorrectly uses `this`. You probably want to do the following:

```
$.fn.removeStep = function() {
 // `this` is now a reference to the jQuery Object on which `.removeStep()` was invoked 
 this.closest('div.sort').remove();
 $('#sortable').sortable('refresh');
 // Allow chaining
 return this;
}
```

Now, you can omit the `onclick="removeStep();"` from your HTML template, and use something like this in jQuery:

```
$('.remove').live('click', function() {
 $(this).removeStep();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias! thank you so much for the fixes! i'm trying as soon as customers stop phone me, damn monday morning! Thank you for the little jquery lesson about 'this' object, it's very clear and helpful!

Comment: Just another question: what's $.fn.? can you show me how my script section has to look like? i'm a bit confused! thank you!

Comment: Just place the `$.fn` thing inside the `$(document).ready(function() { }` block, at the top. By using `$.fn`, we can add new functions and features to the jQuery Object. Basically, what I did is create a little jQuery plugin there.